# How to efficienty count from 0000 to 9999 in a digit display?

Tags: c, microcontroller

I've n display that count from 0 to 9. I'd like to make an efficient code for a micro in C language. What I've wrote is:

```
dis_value[0]++;
if (dis_value[0] > 9) {
    dis_value[0] = 0;
    dis_value[1]++;
}
if (dis_value[1] > 9) {
    dis_value[0] = 0;
    dis_value[1] = 0;
    dis_value[2]++;
}
if (dis_value[2] > 9) {
    dis_value[0] = 0;
    dis_value[1] = 0;
    dis_value[2] = 0;
    dis_value[3]++;
}
if (dis_value[3] > 9) {
    dis_value[0] = 0;
    dis_value[1] = 0;
    dis_value[2] = 0;
    dis_value[3] = 0;
}
```

Where from 0 to 3 are display module number.

Is that the best way?

Or maybe is better a single counter of 16bit that is split into 4 different part?

Comment: How do you define "best"? Does your current approach not work?

Comment: You can nest the next digit control inside the previous, since they won't change until the previous rolls over. When the l.s.digit chnages from say `0` to `1` you are unnecessarily checking all the other digits.

Comment: Why not just dump this out as a string (`sprintf(output, "%04d", value)`) and then display each digit `d - '0'`? Unless you're changing the values thousands of times per second this is usually efficient enough.

Comment: Perhaps because `printf`family can be a very expensive option on a basic micro.

Answer (score 4):

You can nest the digit reset or increment

```
dis_value[0]++;
if (dis_value[0] > 9) {
     dis_value[0] = 0;
     dis_value[1]++;

     if (dis_value[1] > 9) {
          dis_value[1] = 0;
          dis_value[2]++;

            if (dis_value[2] > 9) {
                dis_value[2] = 0;
                dis_value[3]++;

                if (dis_value[3] > 9) {
                    dis_value[3] = 0;
                }
           }
      }
  }
```

By doing above you are not unnecessarily executing all the `if`s.

Answer (score 3):

```
char *inc(char *buff, unsigned *i)
{
    unsigned tmp = ++(*i);
    buff[0] = tmp % 10;
    tmp /= 10;
    buff[1] = tmp % 10;
    tmp /= 10;
    buff[2] = tmp % 10;
    tmp /= 10;
    buff[3] = tmp % 10;
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, depending on the microcontroller, div and modulo functions can be quite expensive, or even emulated => very expensive.

Comment: @GemTaylor on every platform with hardware multiplication == all modern - it is not https://godbolt.org/z/iw5DgI   Only old 8 bit arch are affected.

Comment: But you aren't doing multiplication, but division (modulo). On 8086, division could take up to 250 cycles, for example, compared to 4 for an internal register op.

Comment: @GemTaylor `% 10` and `/ 10` using divisions are very naive implementations

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

void delay(int number_of_seconds)
{
    int milli_seconds = 1000 * number_of_seconds;
    clock_t start_time = clock();
    while (clock() < start_time + milli_seconds);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    int arr[4] = {0};
    for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j<9; j++)
        {
            arr[i]++;
            delay(1000);
            printf("%i%i%i%i\n",arr[3], arr[2], arr[1], arr[0]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I spotted you want to keep the code with minimal dependencise on a microcontroller.

If you are willing to treat the dis_value buffer as an integer, with one byte per digit, say little-endian, which can be held in a register, which should also be faster, then you can combine the sequence:

```
if (dis_value[N] > 9) {
  dis_value[N] = 0;
  dis_value[N+1]++;
```

It becomes (with @kiran 's nesting)

```
if ((dis_value&(0xf<<(N*8)))==(10<<(N*8)))
{
    dis_value+=(0x100-10)<<(N*8);
    if ...
}
```

Where I am presuming the compiler will resolve the constant expressions. 
It would also be good to reverse the addition and the if in order to improve conditional pipeline evaluation, if your controller has a pipeline, but that means writing assembler code.

The following pseudocode should give the idea. The next condition is evaluated using the value before the addition, so the two operations can be performed in parallel. If you were actually encoding this to a circuit, this is an obvious optimisation:

```
bool do0 = ((dis_value&(0xf<<(0*8)))==(9<<(0*8)))
dis_value++;
if (do0)
{
    bool do1 = ((dis_value&(0xf<<(1*8)))==(9<<(1*8)));
    dis_value += (0x100-10)<<(0*8);
    if (do1)
    {
        do2 = ((dis_value&(0xf<<(2*8)))==(9<<(2*8)));
        dis_value += (0x100-10)<<(1*8);
        if (do2) ...
    }
}
```

The next question to ask is how can you minimally update a segmented display for an increment!

Answer (score 0):

simulate math addition would suffice, checking from the lowest digit to the highest.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void incr(int dis_value[], int n) {
    ++dis_value[0];
    for (int i=0; i+1<n; ++i) {
        if (dis_value[i] < 10) break;
        dis_value[i+1] += dis_value[i] / 10;
        dis_value[i] %= 10;
    }
    dis_value[n-1] %= 10;
}

void echo(int dis_value[], int n) {
    for (int i=n-1; i>=0; --i) printf("%d", dis_value[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int dis_value[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};
    for (int i=0; i<10000; ++i) {
        incr(dis_value, 4);
        echo(dis_value, 4);
    }
    return 0;
}
```